# Is it possible make scroll invisible in facebook when we are playing a game?

Tags: facebook

We are coding an application for facebook. it´s a game with diferent kind of levels, and in on level we use the navigation keyboad, and when we press down key or up... the page move because the scroll, so we wanna make the scroll invisible, is this possible? we don´t wanna make it invible in all levels, just in someones.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stop key press event propagation so the main page doesn't get notified when you press a key in your game area (by returning `false` at the end of `onKeyDown()` for example).